# Cannot add Outlet connection from Button to ViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to create an IBOutlet connection/reference from my button to my UIViewController in Xcode, but it is only giving me the "option" to add an Action connection. I am trying to utilize the viewDidLoad and baselineAdjustment to vertically center the buttons label when the text scales to fit the width, but am not having any luck.

Does anyone have a suggestion or know what I'm doing wrong?

[image]

EDIT: Adding a few more screenshots for clarity

If I select my main Scene View, the class is of type ViewController.  If I select the view that the Button in question is a part of(it is in a ContainerView), it is of class UIViewController and the options do not present a choice of ViewController.

[image]
[image]

Comment: please refer my answer. you need to create a new `.swift` file and implement a new UIViewController.

Comment: I have edited my answer with instructions to create a new Subclass of UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the you have multiple ViewControllers in storyboard. Ideally, each View controller in the storyboard is supposed to be of only one type of UIViewController implementation and it's also true the other way around. so, If you have say 3 UIViewControllers in Your storyBoard, then you will need to create 3 `.swift` files which implement UIViewController like so:

```
 abcVC:UIViewController { .....
 efgVC:UIViewController { .....
 ViewController:UIViewController { ..... //this is the default one you get.
```

and then set the class of each ViewController in your storyboard to one of each of the above.

if your ViewController which has the button you want to outlet has a class type abcVC, then you can outlet your button only in `abcVc`'s implementation in `abcVC.swift`.

Hope it makes sense. to see how to set class, refer @Vadim F. 's answer.

and if you happen to upvote this answer, please also consider upvoting @Vadim F. 's answer.

This is how you can crate a new `.swift` file while subclassing a UIViewController: `File -> new -> File -> Cocoa touch class -> #make it subclass of UIViewController and give it a unique name eg: abcVC`

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! This got me where I needed to be. Just to anyone that happens to come across this same problem and finds this question, if the newly created UIViewController subclass doesn't show up in the dropdown list when assigning, restart xcode and it should show up.

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the right class subclassing the UIViewController, make sure when you are doing it, you choosing the UIViewController and not the View or the safe area.

[image]

Let me know if it solved it

Answer (score 1):

Certify that your ViewController in the Storyboard is of the class ViewController (i.e your view controller) and not from UIViewController.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. This is the default ViewController created by Xcode when creating the project, right? Why would I change it's type from how it's created? In the examples that I've seen of people utilizing this method, the 
class ViewController: UIViewController
stays the same as initialized.

Comment: You're right, you don't need to change the name of the class, there is no problem. I haven't made myself clear. You need to change the class of your view controller inside Main.storyboard in interface builder. You can only connect outlets in interface builder if the class of your object matches the class you're trying to connect.